# Rotating MKMapView based on CLLocation.course

Tags: ios, iphone, objective-c, ipad

I've been digging around for an answer almost whole week with no luck at all, the idea is to have MKMapView oriented based on CLLocation course - **not heading**, because heading actually represents the device orientation and I don't want this.

Basically the goal is to display a map just like every navigation device that most of us are using in our cars. map is always oriented according to your course/direction of movement.

Comment: How is heading not also your direction of movement?  You would have the device mounted facing the front...

Comment: What if I mount my device a bit different then facing the front? Tilted 30 degrees towards me for example?

Comment: Have you tested to make sure it doesn't just still report the direction of travel?  I am hard pressed to believe so many navigation applications do anything but read the heading.  And in fact a number of them sort of report the wrong direction until you start moving...

Comment: Yep, I have tested it. Its just the direction of your iphone's compass - meaning the device orientation.

Comment: And have you tested commercial apps to see what they do?  I really think you are pre-optimizing for a problem that does not generally exist.   Also, heading from CLLocationUpdate should have nothing to do with where the phone is pointed, only the direction of travel.

Comment: Exactly, the right thing is the heading received from CLLocationUpdate, but I cannot rotate the map according to it's value. I have to turn on setUserTrackingMode to MKUserTrackingModeFollowWithHeading in order to rotate the map, which does it automatically. That specific rotation that comes from MKUserTrackingModeFollowWithHeading is wrong, its based on the compas. At least these are my observations and tests :(

Comment: I see! Interesting. I fear I cannot help further...